# jquery accessing data() of window.parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In the parent window I have:

```
<input type=text size=100 id="picker1" data-listoption="1" data-type="size">
```

then within the iframe I have

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var parent_input = $("#picker1", window.parent.document);
    var searchdata = $(parent_input).data();
        var listtype = $(parent_input).data('listoption');
    console.log(searchdata);
        console.log(listtype);


});
```

and both outputs in the console are empty.  What is missing here?

Comment: you can't access the dom of another (parent) frame.

Comment: Are you sure you can scope a selector by the parent window?

Comment: not sure what you're trying to achieve with this but have you tried html() rather than data()? also, is it in the same domain? maybe it is not accessible.

Comment: Try calling `parent_input.data('listoption')` without `$(parent_input)` and it's an already jQuery object

Comment: I can get the individual data values with parent_input.attr('data-listoption');

Comment: Try `$("#picker1", top.document)` or `$("#picker1", parent.document.body); `

Answer (score 3):

Jquery does not provide the ability to scope a selector using a window's parent.  But you can access jQuery on the parent from the child using `parent`.

Try:

```
var parent_input = parent.$("#picker1");
var searchdata = $(parent_input).data();
var listtype = $(parent_input).data('listoption');
console.log(searchdata);
console.log(listtype);
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/AEj4Z/

Comment: I get TypeError: window.opener is null  when trying it with window.opener.$("#picker1");

Comment: @BethB  I have provided a fiddle but I may have misunderstood your request, I thought you were using a new window and not an iframe.

Comment: `window.opener` is for accessing the opening window of a popup. But just using `window.parent` or just `parent` should work, I’ve edited your answer in this regard. Obviously, it requires jQuery to be embedded into the parent window as well.